# How to run Vue Dev Server within a Docker container on a custom domain?

Tags: docker, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to have my app running on `local.myapp.com` instead of `localhost`.

Notice: On the host machine inside `/etc/hosts` I have `127.0.0.1 local.myapp.com` entry and my docker-compose configuration has `ports: 80:80`.

When I run this command on the host machine: `yarn serve --port=80 --host=local.myapp.com` everything works and I can access my Vue application by `local.myapp.com`. However I can't configure it the same way using Docker.

All commands below are run within the docker container:

Entering `http://local.myapp.com/` with `yarn serve --port=80` - gives me *Invalid Host header*

Entering `http://local.myapp.com/` with `yarn serve --port=80 --host=local.myapp.com` - gives me *ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE*.

Doing `wget http://local.myapp.com:80` inside container works.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you post the entire docker-compose file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from just running your Vue container, there are a few other things that you need to setup for this to work.

Assuming you already have a `Dockerfile` for your Vue app, you need to set an extra container for a reverse proxy. It might look something like this:

```yaml
services:
  ...
  
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - vue
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx_conf/:/etc/nginx
```

and a configuration inside `nginx_conf`

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name local.myapp.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://vue;
            proxy_buffering on;
            proxy_buffers 12 12k;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason you're getting empty response and invalid host header is because the container's localhost is different from the host's localhost.